# Collection View with add image button at the end

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a collection view full of images and i need the last cell to be a button so when it is clicked i can upload a photo or take it with the camera, any ideas on how to do this??

My cellForItemAtIndexPath looks like this:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell*)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionViewcellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UICollectionViewCell * cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];


UIImageView * imageView = (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:101];

imageView.image = [arrayImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[cell.layer setBorderWidth:2.0f];
[cell.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];

return cell;    

}
```

Comment: BTW i already know how to get the camera, save a photo and upload it i only need the last button to always run that method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add button at the end of collection view in storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31577984/add-button-at-the-end-of-collection-view-in-storyboard)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the easiest and proper way would be the create a custom cell with a delegate called when the button is tapped, and implement your delegate in your collection view controller so that you can respond to the button event.

*AddImageCell.h*

```
@protocol AddImageCellDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void)cell:(AddImageCell *)cell didAddImage;
@end

@interface AddImageCell : UICollectionViewCell
{
    id <AddImageCellDelegate> _delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet id<AddImageCellDelegate> delegate;
```

*AddImageCell.m*

```
@synthesize delegate;

- (IBAction)didTapAddImageButton:(id)sender {
    [delegate cell:self didAddImage];
}
```

*TableViewController.m*

```
-(UICollectionViewCell*)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionViewcellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [...]

    cell.delegate = self;
    return cell;
}
```

And implement your delegate method in your collection view controller, as you would have done with another delegate. Hope this will help you!

Comment: This will make it difficult to work with selection. Better use a footer section described in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31577984/add-button-at-the-end-of-collection-view-in-storyboard