# Add button at the end of collection view in storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionViewController` in a storyboard. I know how to add cells and modify them but for some reason I can't add any other view or UI element after my `UICollectionView`.

Is there a way to do this in the storyboard? If not how can I do this programmatically?

Comment: you can add `SectionFooter` to collection view.

Comment: I cant believe it was that simple. Somehow I feel this post should be deleted

Comment: I think you were confused about the approach to be used to add the button. But for it's implementation you can find lot of solutions. So the question may help some one who have no idea about this approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In storyboard you can enable it by selecting the radio button title "Section Footer", for your UICollectionView and then by dragging UIButton there. You can also override this function:

`- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

You may also need to set Footer's reference size if you are `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`

Comment: I have been struggling with this. I added the fotter but the function: `- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath ` is not gettting called, and I dont know how to add reference size

Comment: just figured it out, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Swift 2.1 Solution :

In Storyboard select `Collection View > Attributes Inspector > Enabled Section Footer`

Once that is enabled, a section view will appear, and you can drag your views to it.

`Select the header view, and set the Identifier`. ex :`FooterViewID`

Next, In you related view controller file,write :

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    let footerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(kind, withReuseIdentifier: "FooterViewID", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    return footerView
}
```

The footer now should appear in your interface bottom.